# Threads were in waiting state while getting a resource from JedisPool

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, jedis

I'm using jedis to connect with redis server. Redis ip value is configured in a separate file and I'm trying to load the file during initialization

```
private static JedisPool pool;

public static void initRedisClient() throws Exception {
   String redisConfigPath = "/conf/redis.properties";
   Properties docsRedisProp = RedisUtils.loadProperties(redisConfigPath);
   pool = new JedisPool(docsRedisProp.getProperty("redisserver"));    
   }
}
```

And my `mget` method to fetch multiple keys from redis are as follows

```
public static List<String> mgetDataFromRedisCache(String[] keys) throws CacheException {
        Jedis jedisCon = null; 
        try {
            jedisCon = getJedis();
            jedisCon.select(1);
            return jedisCon.mget(keys);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warning("Exception while fetching data from Redis Client. EXCEPTION=" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (jedisCon != null) {
                returnJedis(jedisCon);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I have given incorrect ip value in property file - the request thread accessing it is waiting for prolonged period of time. My request should not get stalled due to unavailability of resource in the pool.

Here I'm attaching the thread dump of stalled threads (ie; threads that were in waiting state)

```
###_http-nio-8443-exec-140" #104908 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f247805f000 nid=0x4266 waiting on condition [0x00007f220a4df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006fe438408> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:524)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:438)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:84)
    at com.retail.store.RedisClient.getJedis(RedisClient.java:53)
    at com.retail.store.RedisClient.mgetDataFromRedisCache(RedisClient.java:82)
```

How could I achieve this? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Did you find out anything on this topic? We are facing the same problem when using redis with spring-data-redis (but also Jedis as client)

Comment: @woezelmann setting `setMaxWaitMillis` helped me. Have explained me in my answer below.. please look into it. hope it helps !!

Answer (score 3):

The redis server ip is maintained in a property file and loading it during runtime.

The property file contains default ip. But when I deploy the same in my development setup the redis ip should have been changed but I missed doing so. My development setup couldn't connect with the given ip.

Jedis has the following default configurations

> maximimum active connections = 8
>
> readtimeout = 2000

`Maximum active connections` is the maximum number of active connections the pool can hold concurrently.

`read time out` is the maximum time is milliseconds that is set when the connections is established and is ready to receive data via the established connection.

In our case the connection is not established (for first 8 threads) and it's never killed - the connection is the **timeout** is not set for these connections. The other threads which makes `get` call to redis now goes to park `WAIT` state.

By setting the following pool configurations (ie; setting maximum wait time for establishing the connections) we can avoid the threads going to prolonged wait state

```
JedisPoolConfig jedisConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
jedisConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWaitInMillis);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create jedis connection with a short timeout, using the appropriate [constructor](http://javadox.com/redis.clients/jedis/2.2.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#Jedis(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)).

```
Jedis jedisCon = public Jedis(String host, int port, int timeout);
```

Comment: I guess the default time out value is `2000` milli seconds.. which is 2seconds ...

Comment: Will this 2seconds cause a thread to get stalled in app servers?

Comment: Like when there are too many request hitting the app server - will this 2s cause a great impact - so that the requesting threads get stalled ?

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 So it's not the initial connection that causes problems. Can you add logs to your code and find the line causes blocks the execution?

Comment: Yes, it's not the initial connection that causes problem - the request is getting stalled during `mget` (while obtaining multiple keys from redis). Have edited the question with thread dump logs of stalled request. please look into it..